# Free VSTi for EDM bass?

Tags: vst, bass, virtual-instruments

Since I've started producing music, I've searched for a  good VST instrument plug-in for making EDM bass, like in KSHMR's song "Secrets" or similar. I've searched in [vst4free](http://www.vst4free.com/) and other VST pages, but nothing was found.

I ask for free VST because I'm using LMMS and don't want to spend money in synths.

Comment: @jonhatansmith I'll try it the next time, I'm from Spain

Comment: No problem ;), I've edited your post, it only needs to be peer reviewed in order to display the correction  :)  .

Comment: At the minimum, give a specific time in the video where the desired timbre can be heard. With that said, I've reviewed the video several times and could not find anything out of reach of the generic subtractive synthesizer included with every DAW suite. I can post some of my own VSTi plugins if you're simply searching for *anything* new regardless of whether or not it's related to your question. Notwithstanding, I believe you're simply inexperienced in sound design and can't fathom the sequence of signal processors that create the audio heard in your example. I'd recommend you experiment more.

Answer (score 2):

Togu-audio-line makes some pritty dope synths like TAL-NoiseMaker and TAL-Bassline 101.

Other than that U-He has a few decent free plugins. The best of them I find Tyrell n6.

Other than that I could advise using some distortion on your bassline which brings out the low mids to get the KHSMR kinda bass you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

NUSofting makes a free VSTi called [daHornet](http://nusofting.liqihsynth.com/freeplugins.html) - A Classic VA.

Cheesy and old school but might work

Answer (score 0):

This one wasn't out jet, when you posted this question. "Vital" is a free option these days, pretty similar to "Serum".
You would only have to pay if you want more presets and unlimited text to speech/audio. Also there are a lot of tutorials out there, to spend your free time on ^^